# Excel - Identify a value in one sheet vs values in another with different ranges

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I need some help with an excel formula or format that can help me with the following:

## TABLE 1

```
(Row) |(a) ID | (b)FROM | (c) TO | (d) VALUE 
(1)      123       0        1          50
(2)      123       1        2          50
(3)      123       2        3          50
(4)      123       3        4          50
(5)      123       4        5          60
(6)      123       5        6          60
```

## TABLE 2

```
(Row) |(a) ID | (b)FROM | (c) TO | (d) VALUE 
(1)      123       0        4          50
(2)      123       4        6          60
```

So table one has been incremented to 1 (from and to) whereas table two contains ranges with the values. The incremented values in table 1 should equal the values in table two if the range in table one falls within the range from table 2.

## OUTPUT

```
 (Row) |(a) ID | (b)FROM | (c) TO | (d) VALUE 
(1)      123       0        1          50          TRUE
(2)      123       1        2          50          TRUE 
(3)      123       2        3          50          TRUE 
(4)      123       3        4          50          TRUE
(5)      123       4        5          60          TRUE
(6)      123       5        6          60          TRUE
```

Basically ID'123' has a value of 50 for the increments from 0 to 4 and value of 60 for the increments from 4 – 6 and as per TABLE 2 0-4 = 50 and 4-6 = 60 therefore the statement should be TRUE.

```
    =IF(AND(A1=table2!a:a, table1!B1>=table2!b:b,table1!a1<table!B:B),IF(table1!d2=table2!d:d, TRUE,FALSE))
```

It might be with the way excel deals with ranges etc?

Comment: Just to be sure, for ID'123' you sure it isn't 0-4 and value of 50? As you do say it is 4-6 with value 60.

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the values correctly. so yes 0-4 = 50 and 4-6 =60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the answer from @tigeravatar (credits to him/her) but if you haven't got a ordered list I have created something below that doesn't need that. If table two is not ordered by ID number you could use this formula in cell E2 and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(IF(B2>=INDEX(table2!$A:$D,MATCH(D2,table2!$D:$D,0),2),IF(C2<=INDEX(table2!$A:$D,MATCH(D2,table2!$D:$D,0),3),IF(A2=INDEX(table2!$A:$D,MATCH(D2,table2!$D:$D,0),1),TRUE,FALSE))),FALSE)
```

This does essentially the same but with an AND statement

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(A2=INDEX(table2!$A:$D,MATCH(D2,table2!$D:$D,0),1),B2>=INDEX(table2!$A:$D,MATCH(D2,table2!$D:$D,0),2),C2<=INDEX(table2!$A:$D,MATCH(D2,table2!$D:$D,0),3)),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

On table1, cell E2, use this formula and copy down:

```
=D2=VLOOKUP(B2,INDEX(table2!B:B,MATCH(A2,table2!A:A,0)):INDEX(table2!D:D,MATCH(A2,table2!A:A,0)+COUNTIF(table2!A:A,A2)-1),3)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. I am not a 100% familiar with the index function, but will this formula work even if Table 2's values are in different positions?Unfortunately table 2 cannot be ordered as per table 2 due to other variables.

Comment: @ChantelleBrink Table2 would need to be sorted by ID number and then by From number for this formula to work, as shown in your provided sample data.  If Table2 isn't already sorted in that manner, I highly recommend doing so to make your formulas efficient.  If it's not sorted (and you insist that it can't be), then you'll need to edit your question to show more representative sample data so that we can better assist.  If it can be sorted by ID and then by FROM, then this formula will work fine regardless of other positions (though may need to update column references to reflect real data)